# correlation many columns with values

Tags: r, filter, correlation

I have data frame (df) with many columns e.g.

```
Var(character):  Val(numeric):  Var.1  Val.1  Var.2  val.2  ... var.n  val.n
A                       1        B      5      C       69        n       25
A                       2        B      69     C       66        n       12
A                       3        B      12     C       21        n       12
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
A                       100      B      123    C       19        n       56
```

I would like to calculate the correlation between each variable. Something like that (values are completely random:

```
      A        B          C         ...           
A     0.25     0.32       0.1256                  
B     0.9      0.47       0.125    
C     0.36     0.12       0.87               
...
```

Comment: what is the exact problem that you encounter? have you checked the help page for the 'cor' function?

Answer (score 1):

If you reformat your data, I think the `cor()` function would do exactly what you want:

```
x <- data.frame(Var=rep('A',100), Val=1:100, Var.1=rep('B',100), Val.1=as.integer(runif(1:100,1,100)), Var.2=rep('C',100), Val.2=as.integer(runif(1:100,1,100)) );
y <- data.frame(A=x$Val, B=x$Val.1, C=x$Val.2 );
cor(y);
```

Gives output:

```
              A          B             C
A  1.0000000000  0.1137819 -0.0007431031
B  0.1137819231  1.0000000 -0.1197911609
C -0.0007431031 -0.1197912  1.0000000000
```

The above code will work with any numeric values. If you want to automate the process of extracting the Var names and values, you can use this (added `Var.blah` and `Val.blah` to demonstrate the generality of it):

```
x <- data.frame(Var=rep('A',100), Val=1:100, Var.1=rep('B',100), Val.1=as.integer(runif(1:100,1,100)), Var.2=rep('C',100), Val.2=as.integer(runif(1:100,1,100)), Var.blah=rep('D',100), Val.blah=as.integer(runif(1:100,1,100)), stringsAsFactors=F );
suffixes <- gsub('Val','',names(x)[grep('Val',names(x))]);
y <- data.frame(); for (suffix in suffixes) y[1:nrow(x),x[1,paste0('Var',suffix)]] <- x[paste0('Val',suffix)];
cor(y);
```

Gives output:

```
           A           B           C           D
A  1.0000000 -0.30723601 -0.16862348  0.13557243
B -0.3072360  1.00000000  0.03207434 -0.14573943
C -0.1686235  0.03207434  1.00000000 -0.08735973
D  0.1355724 -0.14573943 -0.08735973  1.00000000
```

Comment: Values in this topic are random.
In my real df I have 15 variable & values are not integer (numeric like 0.689). Val (First numeric column) doesn't have values 1:100 :/

Comment: @amikoma Use  `grep` to get the column names (if I understand the comment)  `y <- x[grep('Val', names(x))]` if the column names are random.